Get the output of an intermediate layer in Keras for GradCAM for a subclassed model
I am trying to get the output of an intermediate layer for a resnet-style model that I developed using Keras and TensorFlow. My model consists of nested keras.Model objects. For clarity, I am adding the code for my model below:
Model code
class ResBlock(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, filters, activation = tf.nn.relu, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filters = filters
        self.act = keras.activations.get(activation)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.conv = layers.Conv2D(filters = self.filters, kernel_size = 1, strides = 1, padding = 'same', activation = None)
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.activation = layers.Activation(self.act)

    def call(self, x, training = None):
        y = self.conv(x, training = training)
        y = self.bn(y, training = training)
        y = self.activation(y, training = training)
        return y

class ConvBlock(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, padding = 'same', activation = tf.nn.relu, dropout = 0, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.padding = padding
        self.act = keras.activations.get(activation)
        self.dropout = dropout

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.conv = layers.Conv2D(filters = self.filters, 
                                  kernel_size = self.kernel_size, 
                                  padding = self.padding,
                                  strides = 2, 
                                  activation = self.act)
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.activation = layers.Activation(self.act)
        self.dr = layers.Dropout(self.dropout)

    def call(self, x, training = None):
        y = self.conv(x, training = training)
        y = self.bn(y, training = training)
        y = self.activation(y, training = training)
        y = self.dr(y)
        return y


class ResNet(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, 
                 depth, 
                 num_classes, 
                 filters = None, 
                 dropout = 0,
                 layer_activation = tf.nn.relu, 
                 classifier_activation = tf.nn.sigmoid,
                 **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.depth = depth
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        if filters is not None:
            self.filters = filters
        else:
            self.filters = [64*(2**i) for i in range(depth)]

        self.dropout = dropout
        self.layer_activation = keras.activations.get(layer_activation)
        self.classifier_activation = keras.activations.get(classifier_activation)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        first_conv_block = [ConvBlock(filters = self.filters[0], 
                                      kernel_size = 7, 
                                      padding = 'same', 
                                      activation = self.layer_activation,
                                      dropout = self.dropout,
                                      name = 'conv_block_1'
                                      )]
        other_conv_blocks = [ConvBlock(filters = filters, 
                                       kernel_size = 3, 
                                       padding = "same", 
                                       activation = self.layer_activation,
                                       dropout = self.dropout,
                                       name = f"conv_block_{i}") for i, filters in enumerate(self.filters[1:], start = 2)]
        first_conv_block.extend(other_conv_blocks)
        self.conv_blocks = first_conv_block
        self.res_blocks = [ResBlock(filters, self.layer_activation, name = f"res_block_{i}") for i, filters in enumerate(self.filters, start = 1)]
        self.avg_pool = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format = "channels_last", name = "avg_pool")
        self.flatten = layers.Flatten(name = "flatten")
        self.risk_classification_head = layers.Dense(1, 
                                                     activation = tf.nn.sigmoid, 
                                                     name = "risk_classification_head")
        self.dis_classification_head = layers.Dense(self.num_classes,
                                                    activation = self.classifier_activation,
                                                    name = 'disease_classification_head')

    def call(self, x, training = None):
        for conv_block, res_block in zip(self.conv_blocks, self.res_blocks):
            conv_out = conv_block(x, training = training)
            res_out = res_block(conv_out, training = training)
            x = conv_out + res_out

        x = self.avg_pool(x, training = training)
        x = self.flatten(x, training = training)

        risk = self.risk_classification_head(x, training = training)
        disease = self.dis_classification_head(x, training = training)

        return risk, disease

    def summary(self, input_shape, expand_nested = False):
        inp = layers.Input(shape = input_shape)
        out = self.call(inp, training = False)

        model = keras.Model(inputs = inp, outputs = out, name = "resnet")

        model.summary(expand_nested = expand_nested)

Inspired by this post, I created a GradResNet model as follows:
GradResNet code
class GradResNet(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, resnet, conv_layer_idx, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if conv_layer_idx < 0:
            self.conv_layer_idx = len(resnet.layers) + conv_layer_idx
        elif conv_layer_idx < len(resnet.layers):
            self.conv_layer_idx = conv_layer_idx
        else:
            raise ValueError("conv_layer_idx must be less than the number of conv blocks in the ResNet Model")

        if not resnet.built:
            raise ValueError("Please provide a built model or call the model with dummy inputs to build the model")
        self.grad_model = keras.Model([resnet.inputs], 
                                      [
                                        resnet.get_layer(f"res_block_{self.conv_layer_idx}").get_layer(f"conv2d_{2*self.conv_layer_idx - 1}").output,
                                        resnet.output
                                      ])

    def call(self, x, training = None):
        return self.grad_model(x, training = training)

to obtain the output of the intermediate/last convolutional layer of the ResNet. The GradCAM code looks as usual.
GradCAM code
def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, grad_model, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index = None):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output, (_, pred_dis) = grad_model(img_array)
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(pred_dis[0])
        class_channel = pred_dis[:, pred_index]

    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis = (0, 1, 2))

    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
    heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
    heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)

    heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)
    return heatmap.numpy()


def display_gradcam(img, heatmap, title = None, alpha = 0.4):
    img = np.uint8(255 * img)
    heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)

    jet = mpl.colormaps["jet"]

    jet_colors = jet(np.arange(256))[:, :3]
    jet_heatmap = jet_colors[heatmap]

    jet_heatmap = keras.utils.array_to_img(jet_heatmap)
    jet_heatmap = jet_heatmap.resize((img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
    jet_heatmap = keras.utils.img_to_array(jet_heatmap)

    superimposed_img = jet_heatmap * alpha + img
    superimposed_img = keras.utils.array_to_img(superimposed_img)

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (20, 10))
    ax1.imshow(img)
    ax2.imshow(superimposed_img)
    if title is not None:
        fig.suptitle(title)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_size = (224, 224)
    # last_conv_layer_name = 'conv_6_id'
    last_conv_layer_name = 'res_block_6'

    title, img_array = get_random_image()
    img_array = resize(img_array, img_size, anti_aliasing = True)
    img_array = img_array[np.newaxis, ...]
    model = ResNet()
    model.build(input_shape = (224, 224, 3))
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam')
    model.restore_checkpoint()

    # model.layers[-1].activation = None

    # model.summary(input_shape = (224, 224, 3))

    model(img_array)

    grad_model = GradResNet(model, conv_layer_idx = 6)

    heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, grad_model, last_conv_layer_name)
    img_array = np.squeeze(img_array, 0)
    display_gradcam(img_array, heatmap, title = title)

However, upon running my code, I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\geker\Desktop\SymViq\codes\rfmid\tf\gradcam.py", line 95, in <module>
    grad_model = GradResNet(model.nn, conv_layer_idx = 6)
  File "C:\Users\geker\Desktop\SymViq\codes\rfmid\tf\nn.py", line 189, in __init__
    resnet.get_layer(f"res_block_{self.conv_layer_idx}").get_layer(f"conv2d_{2*self.conv_layer_idx - 1}").output,
  File "C:\Users\geker\miniconda3\envs\prnn\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2045, in output
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Layer conv2d_11 has no inbound nodes.

I don't know of any possible solutions. Please help.
